# Why ViewBinding doesn't recognize toolbar?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Recently I found out that android kotlin extension has been deprecated.
Now I am using the `viewBinding`.

with android Kotlin extension. I get no problem with the code below

```
class DetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState:android.os.Bundle?) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details)  
    setupToolbar()
}  

private fun setupToolbar() { 
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar)  
  }
}
```

However with `ViewBinding` as shown below, I get `unresolved reference error: toolbar`

```
class DetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding:ActivityDetailsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding= ActivityDetailsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view=binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        setupToolbar()
    }

    private fun setupToolbar() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    }
}
```

Here is the layout xml.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG6zD.png)

Comment: see if `binding.toolbar` solves your issue @joe voidable

Comment: @sekiro you a genius bro. I was adding the binding to the actual method not toolbar itself. We should prolly play sekiro together

Comment: @sekiro is correct, you have to use binding.toolbar

Comment: @joevoidable accept the answer so others don't have to go through the comments to find the answer

Comment: @MartinZeitler the question is about `viewbinding`, not `databinding`

Comment: `inflating twice certainly makes no sense`, twice?? well I suggest you have a look at the official docs [once](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities)

Comment: You're right, but one still could just `setContentView(binding.root)`... after all `ViewBinding` is just a lightweight version of `ViewDataBinding` (50kb smaller), with limited possibilities.

Comment: @MartinZeitler yea you are right mate but inflating views with `viewbinding` is totally different from `databinding`, Happy coding :)

Comment: @Sekiro I just did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference the `toolbar` by viewbinding instead, try the following

```
class DetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDetailsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding= ActivityDetailsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view=binding.root
        setContentView(view)
        setupToolbar()
    }

    private fun setupToolbar() {
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the id of your toolbar lonely.

You must use that from your binding object:

```
setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);
```

some tips about bindings:

- your id in xml will change to a camel case name in kotlin(e.g. toolbar_main -> toolbarMain)
- the `root` property points to the top most layout in tour xml

[read more here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)